# Can't change color of THREE.Mesh material, which exists in scene in runtime

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, hex, rgb

I have already added some mesh to scene.
I'm trying to change the color of the material.
The color changing occurs via color palette from menu.
Using this jQuery plugin: http://colpick.com/plugin

I know, that color palette can send me a HSB values, but I use the following function from that plugin:

```
$.colpick.hsbToHex(hsb)
```

It returns a string, not int value:

> $.colpick.hsbToHex(hsb)   Receives an object like {h:0, s:100, b:100}
>   and returns the corresponding HEX string (with no #).

Here I'm calling a function to change the mesh color:

```
var buttonColorPicker = document.getElementById( 'color-palette-button' );
buttonColorPicker.onclick = function( sender ) {
    this.changeColorForActiveMesh( this.temporary.colorPicker )
}.bind( this );
```

Here is the material changing function:

```
// Note: colorHex isn't an Int, it's a string in this case
// that's why I'm converting a string to the RGB object
// with the following bit shifting to get an actual Int representation
GC3D.Utils.prototype.changeColorForActiveMesh = function( colorHex ) {
    this.scene.children.forEach(function( item ) {
        if ( item instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            var rgbObject = this.convertHexToRgb( colorHex );
            var rgbInt = ( ( rgbObject.red & 0x0ff ) << 16 )
                         | ( ( rgbObject.green & 0x0ff ) << 8 )
                         | ( rgbObject.blue & 0x0ff );
            item.material.color.setHex( rgbInt );
        }
    }.bind( this ));
};
```

Here I've prepared function for converting from hex to RGB object:

```
GC3D.Utils.prototype.convertHexToRgb = function( hex ) {
    var rgbObject = /^0x?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return rgbObject ? {
        red: parseInt( rgbObject[1], 16 ),
        green: parseInt( rgbObject[2], 16 ),
        blue: parseInt( rgbObject[3], 16 )
    } : undefined;
};
```

There is a `/^0x?` part in Regex, because I'm saving the converted hex value from jQuery plugin to some temporary values.

Proof:

[image]

I also tried to make a test here: http://www.shodor.org/stella2java/rgbint.html
To check how correct counts the final Int my function, but seems to be, it's fine.
So what's incorrect? Maybe there is another way of changing the color in `THREE.JS`?

**UPDATE #1:**

I've changed the type of material from `MeshLambert` to `MeshBasic`, and now palette is changing the color correctly! But it's not a solution of this problem, I'm still wondering why MeshLambert doesn't work well in my code... I was trying to set different ambient/color values, but it works very strange...

For e.g.:

```
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xff00ff,
        ambient: 0x167aff,
        wireframe: false
});
```

It renders as red:

[image]

But 0xff00ff is: [image]
And 0x167aff is: [image]

How it could be red?

Answer (score 0):

As from the screen shot it seems that you are receiving the hex value in correctly.

You can just set the color of the material using the `setHex` function directly.

so the code inside the if condition( the one in line 741) would be something like this

```
if ( item instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
        item.material.ambient.setHex(colorHex);// sets the ambient color

        item.material.color.setHex(colorHex);// sets the diffused color

   }
```

Comment: Where is it exactly incorrect? The palette shows the hex value as it is in the function argument `colorHex`, you may visit a site: http://www.shodor.org/stella2java/rgbint.html, when I've tried the color, which is in palette (as the color you're able to see in screen and its code is the same as on that website, please look at another screen: http://s28.postimg.org/6phagclkd/image.png), also the funny thing, that I've tried statically set a custom color for a test: item.material.color.setHex( 0x0044FF ); it's sort a blue one, it doesn't become a blue, it become green?!

Comment: @GeloVolro: what feels to me might be wrong is the lightning in your secne. ie if you have a yellow in the scene , the blue material will appear to be green, and its similar to what you mentioned in your Updated question also. so just add an ambient white light in the scene and remove all of the other lights, and check

Comment: also if you can provide a jsfiddle or similar that would be helpful.